# Count Orders as "Orders" when total is postive, but as "Returns" when total is negative

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am working on a query to track productivity. It goes By Day then By Sales Rep. For example:

```
                          Monday      Tuesday
      Rep 1
            Orders:
            Total Items:
            Total Sales$:
      Rep 2
            Orders:
            Total Items:
            Total Sales$:
      Rep 3
            Orders:
            Total Items:
            Total Sales$:
```

Currently I have a query that does this but its just total Orders and it does not break it down between Orders and Returns. So there could be 4 "Orders" and 1 "Order" where the total of that order is negative and should be counted as a "Return" but its grouped in with "Orders" so it would output 5. This is how I want the report to look:

```
                          Monday      Tuesday
      Rep 1
            Orders:
            Returns:
            Total Items:
            Total Sales$:
      Rep 2
            Orders:
            Returns
            Total Items:
            Total Sales$:
      Rep 3
            Orders:
            Returns:
            Total Items:
            Total Sales$:
```

Here is my query that currently groups all "Orders" together:

```
SELECT 
mh.Date,
ctls.SalesRep,
COUNT(DISTINCT mh.Orders) as "Orders",
SUM(md.simd1_TotalItems),
SUM(md.simd1_TotalSales)


FROM c_file c LEFT JOIN simh_file mh on c.SalesRep = mh.SalesRep
              LEFT JOIN simd_file md on md.Orders = mh.Orders AND 
              md.simd_seq = mh.simh_seq
              LEFT JOIN ctl_file_s ctls on ctls.SalesRep = mh.SalesRep

WHERE mh.Date >= 20210101
GROUP BY mh.Date, ctls.SalesRep
```

But I want to be able to count "Orders" as Orders where its sales total is positive and "Returns" when the orders sales total is negative. Any advice for something like this?

Comment: This isn't your query :-(

Comment: Yes it is :(I see why you say that though, I changed the names in the select to make things easier to read but didnt change them in the joins :/

Comment: Nope. It still isn't your query. Why not simply paste your query.

Comment: It literally isn't: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
 for the right syntax to use near 'FROM c_file c LEFT JOIN simh_file mh on c.SalesRep = mh.SalesRep
              L' at line 7`

Comment: You really aren't understanding that I changed the names?

Comment: It's not the changing of names that's causing the error

Comment: I'm not getting an error. If you're referring to the extra comma, its extremely easy to hit backspace 1 time.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple...a CASE statement would do the trick:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN [sale amount column] > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) END As 'Sales'
SUM(CASE WHEN [sale amount column] < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) END As 'Returns'
```

The first CASE statement gives you a 1 or 0 depending on whether your sales amount is more than zero, which is a sale, then the SUM gives you the total number of sales for that rep.

The second CASE statement is the same, but for amounts less than 0, which are your returns.

Comment: I will try this out, but I was assuming there would need to be some sort of GROUP needed for the "Order" itself. I am not looking for the total amount if pieces sold and returned. If an "Order" has a positive total sales amount its an order. If it has a negative total sales amount its a "Return".